# Error using graphicx package: paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete

Tags: graphics, errors, texmaker

Using the `\includegraphics` command just like that :

```
\includegraphics{Rplot01}
```

will produce the error:

```
! Paragraph ended before \@tempa was complete Error while using graphicx package
```

This is driving me crazy i am searching for about 3 hours now for a solution and found nothing on this topic.
I only wanted to import an image to my pdf. This shoulnt be so complicated.

I am using TexMaker on Windows 10. Here is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphics}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics{Rplot01}
\end{document}
```

The `.png` file is alse saved in the directory as `test.tex`.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please add a minimal working example for us; it makes it much easier to help you.

Comment: i added the script that causing that error, when i remove \includegraphics{Rplot01} and type anything else in document, it works just fine!

Comment: Show the complete log-file.

Comment: Also, is there a reason you're using `graphics` as opposed to `graphicx`?